# Creating a web protocol like AirPlay

Tags: c++, c, web, udp, protocols

I want to create a web transfer protocol that shares data between 2 devices and I want to build it on top of UDP. How would I do this? Are there any example or open source protocols that I could look at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a good idea of *most* of the AirPlay specification by looking at the ["Unofficial AirPlay Protocol Specification"](http://nto.github.io/AirPlay.html).

As an example of an open source UDP media streaming protocol, check out [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/), in particular the [UDP Media Transport](http://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/group__PJMEDIA__TRANSPORT__UDP.htm).